# MySQL query slowness

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a query that is running really slowly.

it takes about 7 seconds to run.

however, if I remove the "and timestamp > 20130201" from the query, it only takes less than 400ms to run.

I thought perhaps the timestamp field wasn't indexed, but it is, so I am wondering why adding a date like this to a query would cause it to be slow?

I would prefer not to remove that portion of the query if I can, but I dont see why it should be that much slower with it in there.

Query:

```
select p1_score,p2_score,p3_score,p4_score from game where  (p1_user_id='$uid' or p2_user_id='$uid' or p3_user_id='$uid' or p4_user_id='$uid') and turn=0 and timestamp > 20130201
```

Explain:

```
1   SIMPLE  game    range   p1_user_id,p2_user_id,p3_user_id,p4_user_id,turn,timestamp  timestamp   4   NULL    51486   Using where
```

Create SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `game` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `p1_user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p2_user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p3_user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p4_user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `player_one_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_two_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_three_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_four_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_one_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_two_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_three_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_four_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `p1_score` bigint(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `p2_score` bigint(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `p3_score` bigint(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `p4_score` bigint(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `game_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `players` smallint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `turn` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `turn_num` smallint(10) DEFAULT '0',
  `layout` longtext,
  `verify` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `message` longtext,
  `tourn` smallint(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `round` smallint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tourn_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `move_history` longtext NOT NULL,
  `next_turn` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tourn` (`tourn`),
  KEY `by_player_one_email` (`player_one_email`(10)),
  KEY `by_player_two_email` (`player_two_email`(10)),
  KEY `by_player_three_email` (`player_three_email`(10)),
  KEY `by_player_four_email` (`player_four_email`(10)),
  KEY `p1_user_id` (`p1_user_id`),
  KEY `p2_user_id` (`p2_user_id`),
  KEY `p3_user_id` (`p3_user_id`),
  KEY `p4_user_id` (`p4_user_id`),
  KEY `turn` (`turn`),
  KEY `verify` (`verify`),
  KEY `next_turn` (`next_turn`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `round` (`round`),

) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Can you please post the query and the table description?

Comment: post the quesy and table description ...

Comment: In order to answer your question, we'd need to see some specific information, such as the outputs from all "CREATE TABLE X" where X is the name of all tables in your query and the output from "EXPLAIN X" where X is the query that is running so slowly.

Comment: I have updated the question with all that info in it, thanks!

Comment: What's the EXPLAIN output for the query without a condition on the timestamp column?

Comment: 1 
SIMPLE 
game 
index_merge 
p1_user_id,p2_user_id,p3_user_id,p4_user_id,turn p1_user_id,p2_user_id,p3_user_id,p4_user_id 
102,102,102,102 
NULL 
24 
Using union(p1_user_id,p2_user_id,p3_user_id,p4_user_id); Using where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query without the timestamp condition runs fast, having it as a subquery should, in theory, run equally fast. Assuming the performance difference is caused by a bug in the query optimizer, this should have equal performance:

```
SELECT * FROM (query without timestamp condition) t WHERE timestamp > 20130201
```

This is of course just speculation. It's impossible to give a definite answer to the question without knowing the tables, the query, and the explain plan of the query.

**Update:** Now that we have the table description and the explain plan, we see that the query is using the index defined on the `timestamp` column. Apparently this index is not a good pick for this query, since the query ends up examining over 51 thousand rows. You can [tell MySQL that a different index might be better](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html) using an index hint.

For example this should use the index on the user ids, which should perform like the query without restriction on `timestamp`:

```
SELECT ... from game USE INDEX (p1_user_id,p2_user_id,p3_user_id,p4_user_id)
WHERE ...
```

Alternatively you can ask MySQL to ignore the index on `timestamp`, so it should use some other, hopefully more appropriate index:

```
SELECT ... from game IGNORE INDEX (timestamp) WHERE ...
```

The query would probably benefit from creating a multi-column index.

Comment: It is probably faster without the WHERE because there is a LIMIT without ORDER BY (or ORDER BY ON an indexed column).

Comment: Thanks for this information, this has been most helpful, a good lesson in query tuning.